# How to return a string with variables in c

Tags: c, string, debugging, return, character

My program is trying to simulate a vending machine. Everything works except for the part where coins are returned or change is returned. I'm trying to take the amount of cents inserted into the machine and input that into another code outside of the main, and then return a string. Is this possible in C because I keep getting an initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast error. If this isn't possible, any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define NI 5
#define DI 10
#define QU 25



bool isValid(int num) {
    return (num >= 10 && num <= 100 );
}

bool isMultiple(int num) {
        return (num % 5 == 0);
}


char *coinReturn(int insert) {

                                int dimes = insert/DI;
                                int remainder = insert % DI;
                                int nickels = remainder/NI;
                                int remainder2= nickels % NI;
                                char *m = ("Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n",nickels, dimes);
                                return m;
}


int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{  for (int i = 1; i != argc; ++i) {
         int price = atoi(argv[i]);
        if (!isValid(price)) {
            printf("Price muse be from 10 cents to 100 cents.\n");
            break;
        } else if (!isMultiple(price)) {
                printf("Price must be a multiple of 5.\n");
                break;
        } else {
                printf(" Welcome to my Vending Machine!\n");
                printf("Pop is %d cents. Please enter nickels, dimes, or quarters\n", price);

                        int cents = 0;
                        char coin = '\0';

                        while (cents <= price && coin != 'E') {
                        printf(" PLease enter a coin [NDQR]\n");
                        scanf (" %c", &coin);

                        if (coin == 'N'|| coin == 'n') {
                                cents = cents + NI;
                                printf(" You have inserted 5 cents\n");
                        }
                        else if (coin == 'd' || coin == 'D') {
                                cents = cents + DI;
                                printf("You have inserted 10 cents\n");
                        }
                        else if (coin == 'Q' || coin == 'q') {
                                cents = cents + QU;
                                printf("You have entered 25 cents\n");
                        }
                        else if ( coin == 'R' || coin == 'r'){
                                printf("Change requested\n");
                                char *rtn2= coinReturn(cents);
                                printf("%s\n",rtn2 );
                        } else {
                                printf("Unknown coin. Rejected.\n");
                        }
                        int balance = price - cents;
                        printf("You have entered a total of %d cents\n", cents);

                        if (balance > 0) {
                        printf("You must enter %d more cents\n", balance);
                    } else {

                                char *rtn = coinReturn(cents);
                                printf("%s\n",rtn );
                         cents = 0;

                    }

                    }


               printf("DONE!\n");
                return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to work:

char *m = ("Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n",nickels, dimes);

Maybe get rid of the char * and just call printf?

Comment: But i need to return the statement somehow. I can do this with a  printf?

Comment: Nope. You could `malloc` a buffer, use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) to format it, and then return that.

Comment: But all you do with the return is printf it. Why not just do the printf in the function?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to do what you're saying. Here's two solutions you might like:

**Solution 1: using printf instead of returning.**

First of all, you're not actually formatting your string by writing

`char *m = ("Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n", nickels, dimes);`

We need to pass these values to a function to do the actual formatting!

Secondly, I don't see why we need to return from `coinReturn`... when we could simply write

`printf("Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n", nickels, dimes);`

and we're done!

But maybe that's not what we want. Maybe we want to actually return a string pointer for this function, we can make that happen too :)

**Solution 2: using snprintf and returning a pointer to a static buffer**

```
char *coinReturn(int insert) {
    // set aside a buffer for our string.
    static char buf[512];
    int dimes = insert/DI;
    int remainder = insert % DI;
    int nickels = remainder/NI;
    int remainder2= nickels % NI;
    // output our string into the buffer.
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),
        "Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n", nickels, dimes);
    return buf;
}
```

Firstly we set aside some memory to store our formatted string,

`static char buf[512];`

Note it's neccesary to declare `buf` as `static` so it survives the scope of our `coinReturn` function.

512 will be our maximum string length, that should be more than enough here.

Lets have a look at that next part:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),
    "Change returned. %d nickels and %d dimes\n", nickels, dimes);
```

(see: https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

The first argument is the location where our string will be written, `buf`.

The second argument is the maximum number of bytes `snprintf` will write (including the null terminator).

The last arguments are just like `printf` which you're already familiar with.

```
return buf;
```

And finally we can return `buf` knowing the result will be a pointer to our formatted string.

---

Out of these two solutions, the first definitely makes more sense - there are a lot of issues I see with #2 (for example: it isn't thread safe), but it get's the job done if that's all you want here.